# Complicated sentence with mathematical terms

Tags: mathematics

I wrote this sentence (which is supposed to sound complicated) for a work of fiction, but I'm not sure it is correct English:

"The length of one cathetus in a right triangle with equal catheti is the squareroot of half of the squared hypotenuse."

Thanks for any corrections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, try this,

> *The length of **each** cathetus **of** a right triangle with equal catheti is **equal to** the **square root** of half of the **square of the length of the hypotenuse**.*

But why stop there, :-)

> *The length of each cathetus of an **isosceles right triangle** is equal to the square root of half of the square of the length of the hypotenuse.*